# Spring boot does not automatically create database tables on Mysql

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

First I already went over some solution on stacks but they did not work. I make a very basic/learning app on spring / mysql, no tables joining for the moment. The problem is tables are not creating on mysql, while everything is working. I copy my code hereunder.
Thanks in advance for the help

Console:

```
 2021-06-15 11:25:07.895  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 c.j.v.VotingsystemApplication            : Starting 
 VotingsystemApplication using Java 15.0.2 on LAPTOP-BQ48GM36 with PID 
 8464 (C:\Users\The Kash\Downloads\votingsystem\target\classes started 
 by The Kash in C:\Users\The Kash\Downloads\votingsystem)
 2021-06-15 11:25:07.898  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 c.j.v.VotingsystemApplication            : No active profile set, 
 falling back to default profiles: default
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.734  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules 
 found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.736  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data 
 JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.749  INFO 8464 --- [           main] .s.d. 
r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository 
 scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.760  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules 
 found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.762  INFO 8464 --- [           main] .s.d. 
r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA 
 repositories in DEFAULT mode.
 2021-06-15 11:25:08.769  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data 
 repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.628  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with 
 port(s): 8080 (http)
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.640  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.640  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: 
 [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.776  INFO 8464 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C. 
 [Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded 
 WebApplicationContext
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.776  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: 
 initialization completed in 1808 ms
 2021-06-15 11:25:09.924  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
 2021-06-15 11:25:10.415  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start 
      completed.
 2021-06-15 11:25:10.582  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing 
 PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
 2021-06-15 11:25:10.672  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM 
 core version 5.4.32.Final
 2021-06-15 11:25:10.879  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate 
 Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
 2021-06-15 11:25:11.018  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 2021-06-15 11:25:11.260  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform 
 implementation: 
 [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
 2021-06-15 11:25:11.272  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
 j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA 
 EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-15 11:25:11.322  WARN 8464 --- [           main] 
 JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is 
 enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during 
 view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable 
 this warning
 2021-06-15 11:25:11.735  WARN 8464 --- [           main] 
 ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template 
 location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check 
  your Thymeleaf configuration)
  2021-06-15 11:25:11.999  INFO 8464 --- [           main] o.s.b. 
  w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 
 (http) with context path ''
 2021-06-15 11:25:12.013  INFO 8464 --- [           main] 
  c.j.v.VotingsystemApplication            : Started 
 VotingsystemApplication 
   in 4.595 seconds (JVM running for 5.166)
```

VotingsystemApplication.java (main app)

```
 package com.javaenterprise.votingsystem;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication
 public class VotingsystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VotingsystemApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

application.properties

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/VotingSystem
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=rooting1
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
 org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Citizen.java

```
 package com.javaenterprise.entity;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "citizens")
 public class Citizen {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private Long id;

     public Long getId() {
     return id;
     }

     public void setId(Long id) {
     this.id = id;
     }

     @Column(name = "citizen_name")
     private String name;

     public String getName() {
     return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
     }

     public Citizen(Long id, String name) {
     super();
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
     }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
    4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
     <groupId>com.javaenterprise</groupId>
     <artifactId>votingsystem</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>votingsystem</name>
     <description>Voting system in sprin</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: Can you share your main application class? I suspect the package that it’s in means that classpath scanning isn’t finding your entities.

Comment: Andy, I updated with main app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main entry point of your application is in the `com.javaenterprise.votingsystem` package. This means that component and entity scanning will find classes in `com.javaenterprise.votingsystem` and any of its sub-packages. Your entities are in the `com.javaenterprise.entity` which isn't covered by this scanning.

You could solve the problem by renaming your `com.javaenterprise.entity` package to `com.javaenterprise.votingsystem.entity`. Alternatively, you can use `@EntityScan` to specify the packages that you want to be scanned for entities.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following property:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

And Second, Please add a default constructor as well.

So ur entity class will become:

```
package com.javaenterprise.entity;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "citizens")
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class Citizen {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "citizen_name")
     private String name;

 }
```

Comment: Made some more changes in answer

Comment: I copy paste it but still no tables have been created. I just putted up my console log could you see it please. I thnk perhaps there is problem in application.properties what do u think?

Comment: Please check schema should be created before. In your case "VotingSystem" needs to be created before running it.You can also use schema.sql and data.sql in root to create and prepopulate the db.

Comment: I tried with schema.sql & it works which means no problem with connections, but tried again through Entity (as before) it didn't work. So, what to do next ? Do you think this is right way to create projects ? I need your advise because I'm an absolute beginner

Comment: Have you used Spring Data or hibernate?If Spring Data,I hope you have a Repository interface which extends from CRUDRepository/JPARepository.Then it should create the table if schema is already available.But without creating schema it's not possible.

Comment: I have updated the complete set of properties and used lombok for setter and getters

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this in your application.properties file**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root/your username
spring.datasource.password= yourpassword
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kibria

#for mysql dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try implementing Serializable and add DEFAULT Constructor ?

Comment: I've just checked it doesn't work also. What I did is, impelemnt serialzation & make default constructor:  public Citizen (Long id, String name) {}.. no luck